# Can I use string str="id" and then person.str=1?

Tags: oop, c#-4.0

I have a class call Person:

```
public class Person
{
     public int id{get;set;}
     public string name{get;set;}
     //and many others
}
```

Is there a way to set value to property not in the regular way like: `person.id=1`
but use something like `string str="id"` and `person.str=1`?

I want that because I have many properties and I recieve list with the name of the property and his value. so I want to avoid long `switch-case` and use :

```
foreach(var item in MyList.Keys)
{
     person.item=MyList[item];
}
```

Comment: do you have dictionary of properties ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public class Person
{
     public int Id{get;set;}
     public string Name{get;set;}
     //and many others
}




Dictionary<string,object> properties = new Dictionary<string,object>();
                 properties.Add("Id",1);
                 properties.Add("Name", "TestName");

                Person p = new Person();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> obj in  properties)
                {
                    p.GetType().GetProperty(obj.Key).SetValue(p, obj.Value, null);
                }
```

This might works for you. Make sure you have proper casing of propertyname.

Comment: To get value p.GetType().GetProperty(obj.Key, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase).GetValue(p, null);.. but carefully it return object you have to cast back to original type or some generic fuction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) for this or the [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) type in .NET 4.0.